# How to find a point a plane?

Tags: geometry, vectors

Consider the noncoplanar vectors OA(1, -1, -2), OB(1, 0, -1), OC(2, 2, -1) related to the orthonormal basis (i, j, k). Let H be the foot of the perpendicular through O and the plane ABC. Determin the components of the vector OH.

I am trying to use the relation between the normal vector of the plane and vector OH. For this I need the equation of the plane and to determin this I need a point from the plane ABC.

Any suggestions finding the point from the plane ABC? Or any other suggestions for solving the problem?

Comment: You can take any of $A, B,$ or $C$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard method is, indeed, to obtain first a normal vector to plane $ABC$:

$$\vec{N} = \vec{AB} \times \vec{AC}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix}1\\3\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$$

Thus the equation of plane $ABC$ is $-2x+y-z=c$ where $c$ is a constant.

Imposing that $A(x=1,y=-1,z=-2)$ belongs to this plane gives $c=-1$.

Thus the equation of plane $ABC$ is

$$-2x+y-z=-1 \ \ \ (1)$$

and then find $H \in $ plane $ABC$ such that $$\vec{OH}=a\vec{N}=\begin{bmatrix}-2a\\a\\-a\end{bmatrix} \ \ \ (2)$$

plugging these coordinates of $H$ into (1) gives $6a=-1$; thus $a=-1/6$.

Therefore, using (2), the coordinates of $H$ are $(1/3,-1/6,1/6)$.

Comment: Thank you, the z of A is actually -2, but thanks for the answer!

Comment: Sorry for this error. I correct it.

Answer (score 0):

We're in fact given three points in the plane:

$$A=(1,-1,2)\;,\;\;B=(1,0,-1)\;,\;\;C=(2,2,-1)$$

since the directed vector $\;OX\;$ is just hte point $\;X\;$ when $\;O=\;$ the origin..

The plane $\;ax+by+cz+d=0\;$ determined by $\;A,B,C\;$ is obtained solving the system:

$$\begin{cases}&I&a-b+2c+d=0\\{}\\&II&a-c+d=0\\{}\\&III&2a+2b-c+d=0\end{cases}$$

Now, we get that $\;I-II:\;-b+3c=0\implies b=3c\;$, and substituting in $III$ we get:

$$2a+5c+d=0\implies\text{substracting from this }\;I:$$

$$a+6c=0\implies a=-6c$$

and now we can parametrize choosing $\;c=-1\,,\,b=-3\,,\,a=6\;$ , and getting

$$6x-3y-z+d=0$$

Substituting $\;B\;$ we find $\;d\;$ : $\;6+1+d=0\implies d=-7\;$ , and our plane is

$$6x-3y-z-7=0$$

Now, a normal vector to it is $\;(6,-3,-1)\;$ . Fill in details.